# Masonry compress images on the top for the first set of photos

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, masonry

I use Masonry to load photos in the gallery. It works fine, except it compress photos for the first 10-15 seconds and show them as a line. Then they expanded correctly and everything works. Here is my code: `$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({itemSelector : '.box' })
    });`
Here is the screen: http://prntscr.com/bhfvd3 
What can be done to prevent photos stuck and then expand?

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to load after the images have already loaded so that it can calculate the dimensions and know what to do with the images. The best thing you can do is to keep your image sizes low and not load too many images at the same time.

If you have many images you need to load on one page then use pagination or infinite scroll. That will allow the script to calculate only after a certain amount of images have loaded and then it will re-initialise after the user has scrolled down. If you are going to use infinite scroll you will need a script that reloads the script after the new images are loaded.

Comment: I use infinite scroll and load 100 photos per page. New elements are adding fine, the issue is just with first set of photos

Comment: The reason why the first set takes time to load is that you have other scripts running as well, whereas when your infinite scroll kicks in it is only focusing on the masonry script. 100 images are alot to load at a time, try reducing the number and see if you get better results.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment, I'll try to reduce the number !

Comment: Great - if that does not work it may be that it first loads all the images that you have and then executes the script incrementally. I normally use Packery for my masonry script, infinite scroll from Paul Irish https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll with images loaded from Desandro to load the images incrementally http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/